# .net statistics library for forecasting

Tags: .net, statistics, forecasting

Is there a good .NET statistics library for forecasting? I need it to do the following:

Decompose the input dataset with classical decomposition into Seasonal, Trend and Irregular.

ARIMA modeling and forecasts.

P.S.

I had a look at R.NET. Thogh it will hopefully do the above, better solutions are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Math.Net

http://www.mathdotnet.com/

Comment: I don't see anything related to forecasting in math.net library. Can you link to any doc? Thanks.